# existe alguna forma de inspeccionar los elementos como en el pc pero en un navegador chrome de ipad?

Tags: css, html5

tengo un problema con un encabezado y un párrafo, los cuales se hacen invisibles en la pagina de los navegadores de un ipad, pero son visibles en otros dispositivos móviles como por ej una samsung galaxy. quisiera saber si hay alguna aplicación que sea como el inspector de elementos en los navegadores de pc o si me pueden ayudar con este problema. les dejo el codigo:

HTML

```
               <div class="contenedorCeo">
                    <div class="ceo wow fadeInUp">
                        <img src="img/miembro1.jpg">
                        <h3>MATTIAS PRATS</h3>
                        <p>Director General</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ceo wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".1s">
                        <img src="img/miembro2.jpeg">
                        <h3>MIKE GUTIERREZ</h3>
                        <p>Jefe Ejecutivo</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ceo wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s">
                        <img src="img/miembro3.jpg">
                        <h3>SARAH STONE</h3>
                        <p>Coordinadora de Ventas</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ceo wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                        <img src="img/miembro4.jpg">
                        <h3>CHRIS DOLKER</h3>
                        <p>Presidente</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ceo wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".4s">
                        <img src="img/miembro5.jpg">
                        <h3>JENNY JAMMIL</h3>
                        <p>Directora general</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ceo wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                        <img src="img/miembro6.jpg">
                        <h3>PABLO RIVERA</h3>
                        <p>Jefe Ejecutivo</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
.contenedorCeo{
margin-top: 80px;

display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -o-flex;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.ceo{
width: 33.3%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;

display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -o-flex;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.ceo img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
-webkit-transition: 0.75s;
-o-transition: 0.75s;
transition: 0.75s;
}

.ceo img:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2);
transform: scale(1.2);
}

.ceo h3{
position: absolute;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 300;
top: 160px;
color: #fff;
}

.ceo p{
position: absolute;
font-size: 18px;
top: 210px;
color: #fff;
}

.ceo:hover p,
.ceo:hover h3{
-webkit-animation: fadeOut .8s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal forwards;
animation: fadeOut .8s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut{
 from{
     opacity: 1;
 }

 to{
     opacity: 0;
 }
}

@keyframes fadeOut{
 from{
     opacity: 1;
 }

 to{
     opacity: 0;
 }
}
```

Se supone que se deberia ver asi: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en el ipad no se muestra ni el h3 ni el p.

Comment: Podrías utilizar el inspector de Chrome que te permite visualizar como queda tu página en un dispositivo móvil. Cuando abres el inspector, en la esquina izquierda arriba hay un icono que parece un móvil y un iPad. Haz click y escoge el tamaño de tú pantalla.

Comment: Si tienes macOS lo puedes hacer desde Safari eligiendo el dispositivo en la parte de "Desarrollo"

Comment: desafortunadamente no cuento con un mac. en cuanto al inspector no me sirve porque el problema solo se presenta en el dispositivo IOS (en este caso un ipad) como tal.

Answer (score 0):

google Chrome en Android permite utilizar las herramientas de desarrollo de Chrome en el escritorio para inspeccionar el HTML que se cargó desde la aplicación Chrome en el dispositivo Android.

Consulte: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

espero que sea de utilizad.

Comment: por favor añade lo relevante del enlace que mencionas aquí, por que las respuestas con solo links se consideran de baja calidad, toda vez que si el sitio web deja de estar accesible la información se perderá; revisa [answer]

Comment: hola el problema ocurre en dispositivos IOS,para ser mas específicos en un ipad, en dispositivos android funciona apropiadamente como mencione en mi pregunta.